# Draw a spline with tangents with Metapost

Tags: metapost

I wish to reproduce the same figure. Only, the curve is not exactly the one expected and I want to make a loop to trace the tangents.

[image]

```
     \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
     \usepackage{luatex85}
     \usepackage{luamplib}
     \begin{document}
     \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
     \begin{mplibcode}
      beginfig(1);
      pickup pencircle scaled 1bp;

     % parameters
     u = 1cm;
     ymin = 0;
     ymax = 12;
     xmin = 0;
     xmax = 8;

    % make a plain grid
    path xx, yy;
    xx = ((xmin,0) -- (xmax,0)) scaled u;
    yy = ((0,ymin) -- (0,ymax)) scaled u;

    drawoptions( withcolor .8 white);
    for i = ceiling ymin upto floor ymax: draw xx shifted (0,i*u); endfor
      for i = ceiling xmin upto floor xmax: draw yy shifted (i*u,0); endfor
      drawoptions( withcolor black);

   % make a curve
   z0=(u,u);
   z1=(3u,3u);
   z2=(5u,5u);
   z3=(7u,11u);
   path p;
   p = z0 {dir 14} .. z1{dir 63} .. z2{dir 0} .. z3{dir 79};
  draw p;

 % Specify a time along the path
   numeric ta[]; ta0 := 2;

 % Pick the point at that time
   pair a;     a := point ta0 of p;

 % Draw a tangent at a particular point
  path tangent; tangent := (-2cm,0) -- (2cm,0); 
  tangent := tangent rotated (angle direction ta0 of p) shifted a;
  draw tangent dashed evenly  withcolor blue;
  fill fullcircle scaled 3bp shifted a;

  endfig;
 \end{mplibcode}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to get a look at the "spline" and "repere" package of MetaPost.

Comment: You want to make the third segment of the path more "tense"  -- so change `..` to `...` before `z3` in your path.

Comment: And you don't need to calculate the angles to set the directions you can use a pairs in curly braces, like so `path p; p = ((1,1) {4,1} .. (3,3) {1,2} .. (5,5) {1,0} ... (7, 11) {1, 5}) scaled u;`

Comment: Thank you. Here is to draw the tangents using a loop : `for i=0 upto 3:
numeric ta[];
ta[i] = i;
path tangent; tangent := (-5cm,0) -- (5cm,0); 
tangent := tangent rotated (angle direction ta[i] of p) shifted
point ta[i] of p;
draw tangent withcolor magenta;
fill fullcircle scaled 3bp shifted point ta[i] of p ; 
endfor;`To mark the points with a cross, I have to write a macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version with some notes as comments.  Compile with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    numeric u; u = 20;

    % grid
    drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1/4 withcolor 3/4 white);
    z1 = (8, 12);
    for x = 0 upto x1: draw ((x,0) -- (x, y1)) scaled u; endfor
    for y = 0 upto y1: draw ((0,y) -- (x1, y)) scaled u; endfor
    drawoptions();

    % path ff is the one you want with "... = .. tension atleast 1 .."
    % path gg is just for comparison with the default tension

    path ff; ff = ((1,1) {4,1} ... (3,3) {1,2} ... (5,5) {1,0} ... (7,11) {1,5}) scaled u;
    path gg; gg = ((1,1) {4,1} .. (3,3) {1,2} .. (5,5) {1,0} .. (7,11) {1,5}) scaled u;

    % draw a tangent at each point along the path ff
    % draw these first so that they appear underneath the curve

    for t=0 upto length(ff):
        draw 
            (left--right) scaled 2u 
            rotated angle direction t of ff
            shifted point t of ff
            dashed withdots scaled 1/4
            withpen pencircle scaled 3/4
            withcolor 1/2[blue, white];
    endfor

    % now draw the curve(s)

    draw ff withcolor 3/4 red;
    draw gg dashed evenly withcolor 3/4 green;  % this is just for comparison

    % now label the points with letters and crosses.

    % First let's make a cross picture
    picture X; X = image(
        drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor 1/4[blue, white]);
        draw (left--right) scaled 2;
        draw (down--up) scaled 2;
        drawoptions();
    );

    % And finally use a list of strings to control the loop 
    % and the magical "incr" operator to increment the index
    % Note that we have mblibtextextlabel turned on, so each 
    % string is automatically wrapped in "TEX()" by the label macro
    numeric t;
    t = -1;
    for a = "$B$", "$E$", "$F$", "$L$":
        label.ulft(a, point incr t of ff);
        draw X shifted point t of ff;
    endfor

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the green path (with the default tension) is the same as the red path from B..E..F.  Here MP has found a nice smooth curve anyway.  But from F..L the default tension means that the curve balloons out to the right to avoid a sharp turn.  But increasing the tension brings the curve back to the desired line.  Essentially using `...` instead of `..` means the curve will stay within the triangle formed by the two tangents and the segment joining the two points.

Comment: Great ! Thank you for your help and your teaching.